# useEffect dependency is not updating the useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a useEffect hook that is not updating after changing the dependency.
The dependency is a state variable passed through props. Included below is what the code looks like:

```
const MyComponent = ({resource}) => {

// runs after changing resource state
console.log(resource)

useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
      // doesnt run after changing resource state
      console.log(resource)
      setVariable(setDefaultValue());
    
  }, [resource]);

}
```

MyComponent is being rendered for one of two states 'option1' or 'option2' the component renders differently depending on the state. I call the component like so:

```
const [resource, setResource] = useState('option1');
const handleChange = (e) => {
    setResource(e.target.value);
};

return (
    <MyComponent resource={resource} />
)
```

I don't understand why the useEffect isn't running after resource state is changed. The `console.log` on the outside of the useEffect show the change state, but the `console.log` inside of the useffect isn't run after changing state.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but that wasn't the question asked. The question is why doesn't the useEffect see the change and run? useEffect is made to run after the dependency has changed, so the async process that you mention isn't the problem here.

Comment: @Andy That isn't the problem. The `useEffect` would wait for that value change

Comment: Is the useEffect running on the initial render?

Comment: it is running on the initial render

Comment: What calls `handleChange`? Is `e.target.value` different from what it was before? An example that meets in the middle between your real code and what’s currently in the question would help a lot – create a dummy component with two buttons that each just call `setResource` with a different value, and post the complete [mre] into your question, to narrow down where the source of the problem is.

Comment: It seems like a pretty standard use case and you're doing things correctly. Can you add a codepen to replicate the issue?

Answer (score -1):

Oh, you can change code the following above try:

```html
//Parent Component
const [resource, setResource] = useState('option1');
const [variable,setVariable] = useState();
const [loading,setLoading] = useState(false);
useEffech(()=>{
  let fetch_api = true;
  setLoading(true);
  fetch(URL,options).then(res=>res.json())
    .then(res=>{
       if(fetch_api){
          setVariable(setDefaultValue());
          setLoading(false);
       }
    });
    return ()=>{
        //remove memory
        fetch_api = false;
    }
},[resource]);
const handleChange = (e) => {
    setResource(e.target.value);
};

return (
    <MyComponent variable={variable} />
)


//Child Component
const MyComponent=({variable})=>{
  
  return <>
    
  </>
}
```

Comment: Where did all of this extra `fetch` code come from, and what’s the part that answers the question?